# Add shadow under custon Container View in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Here is my problem : I am trying to add a shadow under a container view.
This container view has a type which I created. Actually this type is just a custom static table view.

Here is the declaration of this container view :

```
@IBOutlet weak var trackingTableView: TrackingTableView!
```

I have tried to change some layer attributes and It worked for simple `UIView`, but not for the container view :

```
trackingTableView.view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
trackingTableView.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5,0.5)
trackingTableView.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
trackingTableView.view.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
```

Obviously It didn't work, can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either it or its superview is clipping to bounds.  Try adding:

```
trackingTableView.view.layer.masksToBounds = false
```